# Clion can't find external module in python file

Tags: python, cmake, clion

Hell everyone,
I'm using CLion for a C++ project.
I have a some python files in this project too. ( boost python).
The python files import a module generated by cmake.
It works properly if I do :

> $ cd buildDir
>       $ python mypythonFile.py

But in CLion, It can't find the lib imported.
So no autoCompletion, etc and everything is red.
I tried this in the cmakeList.txt:

> set_target_properties(mymodule PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT
>   "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}" )

I thought since CLion use cmake, he'll use this PYTHONPATH but it doesn't work.
I saw similar questions on CLion's forum but with no answer.
So i thought I'd ask here.

Thank you all.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

CLion uses CMake for creation a project model (extracts compiler switches for c/cpp files, detects files that need to be compiled and etc), but it does not inherit the environment. At least in current implementation.

The problem is that there is a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3090) in CLion about overriding PYTHONPATH. As a workaround you can set PYTHONPATH in .gdbinit manually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
Did you mean something like that?
set environment PYTHONPATH=/MyPath/
Tried that with CLion reboot, but didn't work.
I got it wrong ?

Comment: With 2016.3 the bug is fixed. So you don't need this workaround anymore. But I meant updating your local .gdbinit with the proper settings for the older  CLion versions w/o the fix.